# Syntax error: invalid error. Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Write telegram bot. Here code:

```
import telebot
import time

token = 'my token'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

def find_at(msg):
    for text in msg:
        if '@' in text:
            return text

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.chat_id, "Welcome! Let start, use command /help to see my functional.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat_id, "To use this bot, send it a username.")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '@' is in msg.text)
def at_answer(message):
    texts = message.text.split()
    at_text = find_at(texts)

    bot.reply_to(message, 'https://instagram.com/{}'.format(at_text[1:]))
```

And when I start `main.py`, I get Error:

> @bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '@' is in msg.text)
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

How to fix that? Help, please!

Comment: Remove `is` before `in` and execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `is` from the line `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '@' is in msg.text)` as :

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '@' in msg.text)
```

Explanation:

To check whether that character in a text just use `in`

Comment: @roganjosh: Thanks !!.